# PHP mysql_query() No such file or directory found?

Tags: php, sql

I have a MySQL database set up with Hostmysite.com. It connects just fine, and the idea of my php file is to take form values and input it into the SQL database. I am trying to create a feature that doesn't allow duplicate entries by comparing the email to see if it exists in the db...

The php code I think is right, but on die() it returns No such file or directory found??? That doesn't make sense.

```
 <?php
   //connection variables is excluded to get to the point of the problem
   $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
   if (!$con){
    die("Connection failed: " .my_sqli_connect_err());
   }

   $email =  $_POST["email"];
   $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $email);

   //see if email exists in database
   $findEmail = "SELECT * FROM rsvpWedding WHERE email='" . $email."';";
   $results = mysql_query($findEmail)or die(mysql_error()); 
?>
```

The:

```
$results
```

Returns a No such file or directory exists? I don't understand the SQL statement is correct and I believe my php code is also correct.

I don't know if this has anything to do with the problem, but this does mix:

```
mysqli_*();
```

with

```
mysql_*();
```

*****UPDATE ******

I believe I understand why I am getting that error of No such file or directory found. According to the web page : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php  When sql_query() is executed it tries to connect to a link that was executed on

```
sql_connect()
```

not

```
sqli_connect()
```

If it can't find one it will try and attempt a connection with sql_connect() with no arguments, if that fails it will generate an error.. From researching online I see that No such file or directory is normally associated with sql_connect() errors.

So i suppose my question to this post sort of changes to how do I create a resource using the sqli_* syntax. I tried

```
$results = mysqli_query($con, $findEmail) or die(mysql_error());
```

but that still doesn't work, it just skips that entire code block... doesn't even produce an error.

Comment: Are you executing the right script file?

Comment: Are you running php on linux?

Comment: @joydesigner no it isn't on a linux web server, it is on a windows if I remember correctly when I created a webserver on hostmysite.com

Comment: You're using mysql and mysqli functions through each other...

Answer (score 3):

This might be caused by mysql.sock file path is not configured properly for php.

1. So please make sure you installed the mysql db engine, and find where the  mysql.sock file is located.
2. Then you need to configure in php.ini file:

Find these lines, configure like the following:

mysql.default_socket = /path/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_socket = /path/mysql.sock
pdo_mysql.default_socket = /path/mysql.sock

3. Restart apache server and mysql service

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix `mysqli_*` with `mysql_*`. It's safer to do it the `mysqli` way anyways:

```
//see if email exists in database
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM rsvpWedding WHERE email=?'); // question mark is a placeholder
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email); // 's' means it's a string
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($result); // assign the result to your $result var
$stmt->fetch();
```

See the docs here:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: How would I do this using MySqli procedural PHP and not PDO?

Comment: @macas This is "object-oriented," not PDO, so it behaves the same as the "procedural" style of coding it. If you strongly prefer to write it procedurally, it's very similar you can just read the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

your not printing anything thats why!
try using mysqli_num_rows($result)

echo that one

if its greater than zero then it exist
if none then youre all good

Comment: True I am not printing anything, but the die() block executes so I don't bother printing anything because I know $results returns false.